# Fortran routine skips lines but is not allowed to.

Tags: fortran, fortran90, read-write

I made a Fortan routine to read a weather file into my program. This file contains 2 header lines and then lines of data for every 10 minutes and is therefor 52562 lines long.

When reading the file with the code below it returns the error `Fortran runtime error: End of file` for `i = 52548` in the `do`-loop.

```
bdst=600
allocate(clidat(int(3.1536d7/bdst),15))   
open(2001,file='church_10m.cli',action='read')
read(2001,*); read(2001,*)
do i=1,size(clidat,1)
      read(2001,*) clidat(i,:)
enddo
close(2001);
```

The file used can be found using this public dropbox link: [church_10m.cli](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4978485/church_10m.cli). I checked and the file does contain the 52562 lines. The line corresponding to `i = 52548` is the last line of the file. The line corresponding to `i=1` is the third line of the file (which starts with 0). So I suspect that some lines are skipped in between. Any thoughts why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a line doesn't contain 15 values (the size of `clidat`) the read statement just goes to the next line and reads the next values. There were a couple of lines in the `church_10m.cli` file that didn't have enough values. (for example line `1957`).

This was a result of the conversion from an excel file to a txt file.